# Log4Postsharp (dead?) with postsharp 2.0 or drop for ELMAH?

Tags: c#, log4net, elmah, postsharp, log4postsharp

Does anyone know if the latest build (march 2010 - i beleive called log4postsharp 2.0) is compatible with postsharp 2.0 community edition?

I have used postsharp 1.5 together the log4postsharp in the past and was very pleased with the outcome.

But log4postsharp seems to be dead, is this true?

SHould i concentrate more on ELMAH?  I really wanted to continue to use log4net...

Any ideas or insight really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I do not think that Elmah is suitable to replace log4postsharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4PostSharp is not compatible with PostSharp 2.0 Community Edition. Nobody has requested a license key to integrate in this project so far.

If anyone wants to maintain this project, I would gladly provide an assembly license key so that it will work for free for everyone.

Comment: @mark @gael: I seem to have got log4postsharp working with the PostSharp 2.0 community edition... What was broken? Did you get it working? Is Log4postsharp really dead?

Answer (score 0):

I'am also using log4postsharp but we're moving to 64bits so I need to use Postsharp 2.0.

Do you (mark smith) have made modifications to log4postsharp to works against Postsharp 2.0 ?